# sorting a list using Collections causes errors

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, lis

i have an object of type MatOfDMAtch and i converted to a list and i want to sort it as shown below using Collections, but when i run the code i receive the below errors.

please let me know why i am receiving these errors and how to solve it.

**CODE**:

```
List dMatchList = matDMatch.toList();
    System.out.println("dMatchList.size(): " + dMatchList.size());

    sortMAtches(0, 100, dMatchList);
}

private static void sortMAtches(double minDist, double maxDist, List list) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    java.util.Collections.sort(list);
    /*for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println("lsit[" + i + "] = " + list.get(i));
    }*/
}
```

**ERRORS**:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.opencv.features2d.DMatch cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable
at java.util.ComparableTimSort.countRunAndMakeAscending(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ComparableTimSort.sort(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Arrays.sort(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Arrays.sort(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.sort(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Collections.sort(Unknown Source)
at test.FeaturesMatch.sortMAtches(FeaturesMatch.java:96)
at test.FeaturesMatch.main(FeaturesMatch.java:91)
```

**UPDATE**:

now i used the comparator interface, but as you see in the acode below at the commented out line, i cant use .compareTo() method!
how to use it?

```
List<DMatch> dMatchList = matDMatch.toList();
    DMatch[] dMatArray = matDMatch.toArray();
    System.out.println("dMatchArray.length(): " + dMatArray.length);
    System.out.println("dMatchList.size(): " + dMatchList.size());

    java.util.Collections.sort(dMatchList, compa);
}

static Comparator<DMatch> compa = new Comparator<DMatch>() {

    public int compare(DMatch arg0, DMatch arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return arg0.distance.???; //compareTo() does not exist??
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must implement a custom Comparator like this (change `getYourValueToCompare()` by your getter):

```
Collections.sort(dMatchList, new Comparator<DMatch>() {
    public int compare(DMatch a1, DMatch a2) {
        return a1.getYourValueToCompare().compareTo(a2.getYourValueToCompare());
    }
});
```

**NOTE:** Remember to implement [equals method](http://www.artima.com/lejava/articles/equality.html) for `DMatch` class or you won't see any sorting!!

Comment: Follow my instructions and implement inner comparator, you will get compareTo method without problem, also **REMEMBER CREATE EQUALS METHOD IN DMatch CLASS**

Answer (score 1):

Either your DMatch class must implement the Comparable interface or you must call Collections.sort( ... ) with an apropriate Comparator that can compare your DMatch objects.

Answer (score 0):

Class `org.opencv.features2d.DMatch` do not implement the interface `java.lang.Comparable`. So it is not comparable by default. You have to write your own `Comparator`.

And call `java.util.Collections.sort(list, new MyDMatchComparator());`

```
public class MyDMatchComparator implements Comparator<DMatch>{

    @Override
    public int compare(DMatcho1, DMatch o2) {
       //compare logic
    }
}
```

Comment: @user2121 Thats why your class do not implment Comparable. You have to implement it your own way for instance: `if (arg0.distance ==arg0.distance) return 0; if (arg0.distance ==arg0.distance) return -1` or what your logic is.